# How to make an underwater filter for pictures

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a project where one part is to make a picture of fish(named water.jpg) more visible. I just don't know what pixels I need to alter to make it work. I've tried keeping only blue, green, or red at a time and I've tried keeping everything but blue, green, or red at a time. I pretty much just need to know what pictures I need to alter. The code I have is just a couple of methods, which all function properly, but they're what I have to base this underwater method on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Picture beach = new Picture("water.jpg");
    beach.explore();
    beach. (INSERT.METHOD.HERE);
    beach.explore();
}

public void zeroBlue() {
    Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
    for (Pixel[] rowArray : pixels) {
        for (Pixel pixelObj : rowArray) {
            pixelObj.setBlue(0);
        }
    }
}

public void keepOnlyBlue() {
    Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
    for (Pixel[] rowArray : pixels) {
        for (Pixel pixelObj : rowArray) {
            pixelObj.setGreen(0);
            pixelObj.setRed(0);
        }
    }
}

public void grayscale() {
    Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
    for (Pixel[] rowArray : pixels) {
        for (Pixel pixelObj : rowArray) {
            int avg = (pixelObj.getGreen() + pixelObj.getBlue() + pixelObj.getRed()) / 3;
            pixelObj.setGreen(avg - 3);
            pixelObj.setRed(avg - 3);
            pixelObj.setBlue(avg - 3);
        }
    }
}

public void negate() {
    Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
    for (Pixel[] rowArray : pixels) {
        for (Pixel pixelObj : rowArray) {
            pixelObj.setGreen(255 - pixelObj.getGreen());
            pixelObj.setRed(255 - pixelObj.getGreen());
            pixelObj.setBlue(255 - pixelObj.getGreen());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not relevant to StackOverflow.

Comment: I mean, it's still java

Comment: What is this `Pixel` class?

Comment: it's this whole 300-400 lines of code

Comment: Can you adjust things like luminosity besides the RGB? You can make the fish stand out by raising the luminosity of the fish and lowering the luminosity of everything else.

Comment: Maybe you should first try to play around with an image manipulation program, such as GIMP, and then try to translate whatever brought you the best results into code.

Comment: How might I increase that?

Comment: The fact that your question is about code being written in Java doesn't necessarily make it relevant for SO. Your question is off-topic as per SO's standards. Please read [help/on-topic] to learn what is on- or off-topic.

Comment: Quality aside (too broad), his question is not relevant to Java but the image-processing tag (which has 16k questions). His question fits that tag so it's not off-topic in my eyes (unless the whole tag and everything else associated with it is off-topic)

Comment: Let me explain what others have posted. Just because you are using Java to solve a problem it does not mean that the problem is Java-related. This is a photography-related problem. A photographer will be a better help than a software developer. Once you know what the root problem is, you can ask for clarification on how to solve the problem using Java.

Comment: I agree with Everv0id, Laf, and hfontanez. The problem isn't that his Java code is broken or wrong, the problem is that they don't know how they should be altering a photo. That they happen to be trying to change it in Java is beside the point.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underwater

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about photography than programming.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach a picture of water.jpg? It might help with understanding of your issue.
Should your negate also be this...

```
public void negate() {
     Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
     for (Pixel[] rowArray : pixels) {
         for (Pixel pixelObj : rowArray) {
             pixelObj.setGreen(255 - pixelObj.getGreen());
             pixelObj.setRed(255 - pixelObj.getRed());
             pixelObj.setBlue(255 - pixelObj.getBlue());
         }
     }
}
```

or am I thinking backwards myself?